# How Can I get IntelliJ to check for _ or __ at the end of Javadoc URLS when it can't find them?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javadoc, oracle-ucm

I'm trying to add Javadocs to IntelliJ for *CIS-Client-11g*. From what I can tell Oracle doesn't offer the javadoc jar file as a download.  The actual documentation is online though here:  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/apirefs.1111/e17350/

However when I try to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> on **cisApplication.getUCPMAPI()**
IntelliJ tries to access:

- http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/apirefs.1111/e17350/com/stellent/cis/ICISApplication.html#getUCPMAPI
  *AND*
- http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/apirefs.1111/e17350/com/stellent/cis/ICISApplication.html#getUCPMAPI-
  *OR*
- The javadoc.jar file equivalents.
  (I initially downloaded the site, zipped it and saved it as *cis-client-11g-javadoc.jar*)

However the actual URL for the method is:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/apirefs.1111/e17350/com/stellent/cis/ICISApplication.html#getUCPMAPI__
(notice the end is "__" ).

How Can I get IntelliJ to check for _ or __ at the end of Javadoc URLS when it can't find them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a configurable item. When the Javadoc URL convention changed in Java 8, an IDEA internal change was needed. (See [IDEA-118970 Java 8 Javadoc for methods not found due to URL syntax change](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-118970)). That was implemented in IDEA v13.1. It looks like the use of the underscore is a non conventional format. Perhaps something Oracle was using before it acquired Sum (and Java). I'd recommend opening a [feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com) asking for that convention to be supported. That's likely in the open source portion of IntelliJ IDEA. So you may be able to create a patch to fix it and supply it so as to get the issue fixed quicker.

Another option (since you apparently have created your own JAR of the documentation) would be to do a search and replace on the anchors and replace the underscores with dashes. If you are on windows, [PowerGrep](http://www.powergrep.com/index.html) would make that a snap. In fact I used PowerGrep to do the opposite at one point when I was waiting for the above mentioned bug fix to be put in place. I "converted" the new Javadoc format anchors for the latest Java 8 early access build into the old version. It was only about 10 or 15 minutes of work.